# How to click on link that many have spaces?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am dealing with a site with the following structure

```
<div class="col-3"
  <field-input>
     <div class=" group-4">
         <input> #Lets call this input 1 </input>
  <field-input>
     <div class=" group-4">
         <input> #Lets call this input 2 </input>
```

I want to pass in values to `input field 1` and `input field 2`. How could I do this? I tried the following and it gives me an error saying

> cannot find elements

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//field-input/div/input").send_keys("myvalue")
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Your locator looks good, is this in an IFRAME?

Comment: No its not. its angular class names

Comment: The locator matches both inputs.  Try "(//field-input/div/input)[1]" to choose the first one.  The alternative would be to keep your xpath, but use find_elements() then work with the discovered elements to send keys.

Comment: Your first solution doesn't seem to work. I am new to selenium. Could you elaborate on your second option a little more on how to iterate discovered elements in a column?

Comment: Would you provide actual error stack trace which selenium throws...??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I am not with my code right now but it says its unable to find the element with the xpath  "//field-input/div/input"

Comment: Make sure it is not inside any frame...if not you should implement `WebDriverWait` unit element present..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the class attribute to your xPath so that it becomes:

```
"//div[@class=' group-4']/input[1]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `Selenium::WebDriver::Wait` until element visible as below :-

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 10)
el = wait.until { driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//div[normalize-space(@class) = 'group-4']/input)[1]").visible? }
el.send_keys("myvalue")
```

**Note** :- If want to access second input just change use `(//div[normalize-space(@class) = 'group-4']/input)[2]` as `xPath`

Hope it will help you..:)